# What is the difference between (for example) p.post {color: #336;} and .post p {color: #336;}?

Tags: css

I've always used this structure in the style sheet:

```
.post {padding: 10px;}
.post h1 {color: #336;}
.post p {font-size: 1em;}
```

with this html:

```
<div class="post">
<h1>title</h1>
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

However, I frequently see this structure in style sheets:

```
h1.post {color:#336;}
p.post {font-size: 1em;}
```

with this html:

```
<h1 class="post">title</h1>
<p class="post">content</p>
```

I'm working on a theme that I will be giving to others, therefore, it's not enough that it works--I want it to reflect "best practices" (and keep me from appearing to be a total newbie).

My attempts to find an answer haven't been successful--perhaps because the search terms (element, selector, css, etc) are too broad.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

(Also, an overdue thanks for past assistance.  This is my first question, but not my first visit to the site.)

Answer (score 3):

They specify slightly different things.

- `p.post` matches a `p` element (and *only* a `p` element) that *also* has a class of `post`.
- `.post p` matches a `p` element that is a *descendent* of another element that has a class of `post`.

The general term for the operators that combine or refine the elements to form a CSS rule is *selectors* or *combinators*. In CSS3 they're defined by [this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). `p.post` is an example of the *class selector*, while `.post p` illustrates the *descendant combinator*.

Comment: A follow-up to verify that I understand: there is nothing wrong with my usual technique, i.e., create a class (.post) and assign values to properties associated with specific html tags (.post p, .post h1, etc). However, if I simply wanted selected paragraphs to have blue text (i.e., no need to style multiple tags), the class selector option would be preferable. Right?  (BTW, I have a link to that w3.org page in my toolbar. I find it very useful regarding things I'm already familiar with on some level, not so much regarding new subjects.)

Comment: Yes. The two approaches aren't "better" or "worse" than one another; they're just two different rules for specifying a target to apply some styles to.

Answer (score 0):

As answered already but with some HTML examples. [] subbed for tags.

p.post
- [p class="post"]Hello[/p]

.post p
- [div class="post"][p]Hello again[/p][/div]